# How to referesh the base page when i login in the iframe colorbox?

Tags: colorbox

I'm invoking the colorbox with iframe option on a click of the button to load my subdomain page.
when the user try to hit my subdomain page, i will check is the user is logged with my php code.

if the user is not logged in, take him to the login page and then redirect him to my subdomain page.

**The following are the challenges**

1. The login will be with only following fields, "user name", "password" and "submit" button. when the user login the subdomain page is a full site. How to handle the resize? (issue is after login which method to invoke like onComplete is on when the content is loaded completely? anything like "onRefresh")
2. when user redirected to my subdomain page how to refresh by base site that is visible in behind the iframe as a overlay **to show "welcome user"**.

Comment: This is pretty hard to follow. Consider posting a link to a dev copy of your project.